# Sorting csv data via php

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a .csv file on my server that looks like this :

```
C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040805.JPG,0.163533
C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040808.JPG,0.170159
C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040819.JPG,0.885534
C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040825.JPG,0.11393
C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040826.JPG,0.0536503
```

and so on. I found a php script that displays these results in my browser which looks like this:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/results/result.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo " ","Record #",$row," "; $row++;
        for ($recordcount=0; $recordcount < $num; $recordcount++) {
            echo $data[$recordcount] . " \n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} ?>
```

But when it shows the csv, the layout is totally messed up, e.g several results in one line.

I'd like to do three things -

-convert the 0.xx to a percentage 
-put the percentage value in the first column and the path in the second
-and most of all, simply have the data stacked neatly so that every line has one result.

Can that all be done in php? and could somebody tell me what parameter I have to tweak to get one result per line and not more?

Comment: you're dumping text into a browser. it's going to rendred by browser rules as html, which means you need to put in `<br>` if you want line breaks. And yes, your calculations can be done in PHP. it's just math.

Comment: Replace the "\n" with "<BR>"

Comment: try this: `echo nl2br($CSV);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isn't that hard, check here

```
if (($handle = fopen("yourfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
            $percentaje=$data[1]*100;
            echo $percentaje."%&nbsp".$data[0]. "<br>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

result:

```
16.3533% C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040805.JPG
17.0159% C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040808.JPG
88.5534% C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040819.JPG
11.393% C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040825.JPG
5.36503% C:/Users/Server/Pictures/P1040826.JPG
```